# How can I make a regular expression which ignores repeated strings, but checks for future valid strings?

Tags: regex

**The Issue At Hand**

I have a CAN log file which contains a series of messages in the following format. I've identified each string in the log file by naming it 'String *n*:' followed by the actual content of the file.

**String 1**: `01 3E 55 55 55 55 55 55`
**String 2**: `01 7E 00 00 00 00 00 00`
**String 3**: `21 51 00 00 66 63 51 00`
**String 4**: `22 00 00 00 00 37 41 31`
**String 5**: `30 00 00 55 55 55 55 55`

There is more content on each log line, but this regex will only be run once I've extracted just this portion of each line from the original log file contents. I've provided a sample of a raw log line below, just in case that somehow helps anyone figure this out more easily.

**Sample Line**: `2023-07-07 05:07:48.896  Tx  7e0   01 3E 55 55 55 55 55 55`

I'd like to make a regular expression which only returns back out pairs of characters before where I see all `00` for the remainder of a string, or `55` for the remainder of a string.  I'm expecting to see results as follows for the 5 input strings, but I can't seem to build the correct regular expression to produce these results.

**String 1**: `01 3E`
**String 2**: `01 7E`
**String 3**: `21 51 00 00 66 63 51`
**String 4**: `22 00 00 00 00 37 41 31`
**String 5**: `30`

Can someone help me build this regex correctly?

---

**What I've Tried**

I've tried using positive lookahead regular expression patterns, but no matter how I try and configure my positive lookaheads, I am struggling to get the right characters back. I'm always either dropping one pair of characters (the `3E` in string 1, or the `7E` in string 2), or I'm not getting matches at all (string 5 gives me back nothing). I've dropped the regex I've been messing with below along with an example of what it's not returning out.

**Regular Expression**: `([0-9A-F]{2,} (?!55|00))+`
**String 1**: Returns `01`
**String 2**: Returns `01`
**String 3**: Returns `21 00 66 63` (No idea how to fix this issue)
**String 4**: Returns `00 37 41` (Again, no idea how to fix this issue)
**String 5**: Returns `null` (Why doesn't it even see the 30?)

Comment: Something like `^.*?(?=(?: (?:00|55))*$)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q1RuYA/1))?

Comment: Damn that was quick. That'll do quite nicely. Thanks a ton @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. Just had to remove the ^ character. Thanks again @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Your desired result for String 5 contradicts your statement, "...where I see all 00 for the remainder of a string, or 55 for the remainder of a string." Perhaps you mean, "...where the remainder of the string is comprised of combinations of the strings `' 00'` and `' 55'`, examples being  `' 00 55 00'`, `' 00 00 00'` and `' 55 55 55'`.

Comment: @ZacharyWalsh I updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76653646/3832970). You could explain that you extract a single match per an input string in the question, it would make it clearer.

Comment: @ZacharyWalsh To your secondary question: `([0-9A-F]{2,} (?!55|00))+` does not match in `30 00 00 55 55 55 55 55` because your expression explicitly matches groups of characters only if they are followed by a space and that space is not followed by 00 or 55. Every character group in `30 00 00 55 55 55 55 55` that is followed by a space is also followed by either 00 or 55, so you get no match at all.

Comment: @CarySwoveland. You're correct. Statement 5 was a bit odd. I technically do need the 00 00 before the 55s. But frankly, that type of message will always be 30 00 00 as the response. And it has no significance to me when decoded to plaintext. But thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You need to edit your question to clarify your requirements. Keep in mind that many members may read your question in future. They should be able to understand it without reading through the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match any chars up to the first occurrence of spaces and then `55` or `00` repeated till the end of the line with

```
^.*?(?=(?: (?:00|55))*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q1RuYA/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of the string (or line)
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=(?: (?:00|55))*$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with zero or more repetitions of a space + `00` or `55` till the end of the string/line.

**UPDATE**

To match these texts inside larger strings, you can use

```
(?<!\S)[a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?: [a-fA-F0-9]{2})*?(?=(?: (?:00|55))*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q1RuYA/2).

*Details*:

- `(?<!\S)` - left-hand whitespace boundary
- `[a-fA-F0-9]{2}` - two hex chars
- `(?: [a-fA-F0-9]{2})*?` - zero or more, but as few as possible, occurrences of a space + two hex chars
- `(?=(?: (?:00|55))*$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a position immediately followed with zero or more repetitions of a space and then either `00` or `55`, till end of string.

This works for you as you extract a single match from any given input string.

Comment: I suspect your answer was downvoted by someone who found it inconsistent with the OP's phrase, "I'd like to make a regular expression which only returns back out pairs of characters before where I see all 00 for the remainder of a string, or 55 for the remainder of a string.". I think we both concluded that was not was not what the asker meant, in view of the desired result for Example 5, which the downvoter may have missed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Forget it, it was a serial downvoter.

Answer (score 1):

To preface, wouldn't you want the initial *00*'s from the last example?

```
30 00 00 55 55 55 55 55
```

```
30 00 00
```

That being said, there are a few ways to do this.

You *could* remove the unwanted values from the line, using a find-and-replace.

```
(?:(?: 00)+|(?: 55)+)$
```

Or, you could use a capture group, to return the wanted values.

```
(.+?)(?:(?:(?: 00)+|(?: 55)+)$|$)
```

If you don't want the initial *00*'s, you can use the following patterns, respectively.

```
(?: 00| 55)+$
```

```
(.+?)(?:(?:(?: 00| 55)+)$|$)
```

Comment: You're totally right. I did want those 00s in the last test string. Thanks for the answer.